# ajax on anchor tag using the href attribute and id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the default function of an anchor tag to be enhance in use of ajax so Im trying to post/get or request a data from id of a specified anchor tag (refer below)

code in my anchor tag

```
<a href="processor.php" class="ajaxanchor" id="2">My Title</a>
```

and the script i use

```
$('a.ajaxanchor').click(function() {
    var location = $(this).attr('href');
    // use jQuery's $.post, to send the request
    // the second argument is the request data
    $.post(location, {jkey: "post", post_id: this.id}, function(data) {
        // data is what your server returns
    });

    // prevent the link's default behavior
    return false;
});
```

but seems not working at all, any one who could suggest, recommend or can give ideas how to make this work please? thanks in advance.

Comment: Open your browser console (F12) and check for errors.

Comment: whether the click handler is getting called

Comment: There's no problem with the code. It's posting the data you given.

Comment: try adding it in a dom ready handler also whether the anchor elements are created dynamically

Comment: fixed :D, i used different approach. Here's the code i used "var location = $(this).attr('href');
    $.ajax({
   url : location,
   type: "POST",
   data : { jkey: 'post', post_id: this.id },
   success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
   {
    if (($.trim(data) == "success")) {
     alert ("success");
    }else{
     alert (data);
    }
   },
   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
   {
    alert ("fail");
   }
  });"